# There is no option to choose storyboard in Xcode 13.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14.3

I'm new to Swift and I want to I want to start a project based on the tutorial I'm following, but I cannot find the storyboard option and language option to select either Swift or Objective-C.

Screen from the tutorial:
[image: This is the screen in the tutorial]

My screen:
[image: This is my Xcode screen]

Comment: I can select storyboard in my Xcode 13.2.1. What is the screen before the screen you are seeing? Are you making sure to select iOS as the project type?

Comment: Don’t start a multi platform app, just select ios

Comment: okay I was selecting a multiplatform app

Comment: Hey - if my answer solved your problem I recommend accepting it so others with similar problems know this question was resolved.

Answer (score 13):

When you open Xcode, ensure you have the **iOS** option selected right under "Choose a template for your new project". From there, you should be able to select Storyboard in lieu of SwiftUI. You likely have Multiplatform selected, which would be why you're not seeing that option.

Comment: Hi @EJZ how do I mark it as the answer , I've done mark it as useful already.

Answer (score -1):

> Update XCODE 14.3

For me I had to select the app under the **IOS tab** option rather than selected **Multiplatform tab** option like this.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly the same as the existing answer.